# is there Backgroundworker for java ( like in .Net )

Tags: java, android

The Backgroundworker that make the process work in background without make lag in application any information about it you will be thanked.

Comment: If you're talking about the UI/Swing, then take a look at [`SwingWorker`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html)

Comment: use [SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html) for gui related tasks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### For an Android App use AsyncTask

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

```
private class DownloadFilesTask extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, Long> {
     protected Long doInBackground(URL... urls) {
         int count = urls.length;
         long totalSize = 0;
         for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
             totalSize += Downloader.downloadFile(urls[i]);
             publishProgress((int) ((i / (float) count) * 100));
             // Escape early if cancel() is called
             if (isCancelled()) break;
         }
         return totalSize;
     }

     protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
         setProgressPercent(progress[0]);
     }

     protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
         showDialog("Downloaded " + result + " bytes");
     }
 }
```

#### For a Java swing application

For a java swing application use either `java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService`
or `javax.swing.SwingWorker`.

Depends on what you want to do:
If you are using `SwingWorker` the done method is executed on the Event Dispatch Thread after the `doInBackground` method is finished. If you use an `ExecutorService` you must take care that the ui related work is done on the Event Dispatch Thread. E.g. with `SwingUtilities.invokeLater`.

***`ExecutorService`*** example from the javadoc

```
class NetworkService implements Runnable {
   private final ServerSocket serverSocket;
   private final ExecutorService pool;

   public NetworkService(int port, int poolSize)
       throws IOException {
     serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
     pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(poolSize);
   }

   public void run() { // run the service
     try {
       for (;;) {
         pool.execute(new Handler(serverSocket.accept())); 
       }
     } catch (IOException ex) {
       pool.shutdown();
     }
   }
 }

 class Handler implements Runnable {
   private final Socket socket;
   Handler(Socket socket) { this.socket = socket; }
   public void run() {
     // read and service request on socket
   }
 }
```

---

***`SwingWorker`*** example from the swing tutorial

```
SwingWorker worker = new SwingWorker<ImageIcon[], Void>() {
    @Override
    public ImageIcon[] doInBackground() {
        final ImageIcon[] innerImgs = new ImageIcon[nimgs];
        for (int i = 0; i < nimgs; i++) {
            innerImgs[i] = loadImage(i+1);
        }
        return innerImgs;
    }

    @Override
    public void done() {
        //Remove the "Loading images" label.
        animator.removeAll();
        loopslot = -1;
        try {
            imgs = get();
        } catch (InterruptedException ignore) {}
        catch (java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException e) {
            String why = null;
            Throwable cause = e.getCause();
            if (cause != null) {
                why = cause.getMessage();
            } else {
                why = e.getMessage();
            }
            System.err.println("Error retrieving file: " + why);
        }
```

Comment: thank you very much but i have got error when i used "SwingWorker" in android eclipse application . i have used your code and also i used the custom method of that code nevertheless the app has stopped because there is error. i don't know what is the wrong with that?

Comment: You were talking about an application and the question is tagged with java. Therefore I thought you are developing a swing application. In android you have to use another approach. Please correct the tagging and make your question more precise.

Comment: I have added the example for an android application (the SwingWorker equivalent in android)

Comment: More respect to you . i have edited tha tags of my question . and sure i have forgot that i want develop android application . i am newbie in java that make me think the programing in android take the same methods in java